# What cable do I need to connect my old commodore64 with a tv (as monitor)

Tags: commodore-64

[image][image]
I want to use an old commodore64. In the 80s we connected a small tv, as a monitor, but the cable for that connection is missing. What kind of cable connection do I need?

Comment: Please edit your images to make them smaller. Around half of it would be already okay. Cut the important parts out, if resolution is important.

Comment: What connections your TV has? C64 can output S-Video and Composite type of signals from the DIN type A/V output connector.

Comment: Have you seen https://dfarq.homeip.net/how-to-connect-a-commodore-64-to-a-television/ ?

Comment: To close voters: The question that this seems to be considered a duplicate of asks for *modern* TVs. This one doesn't. Options might be different.

Comment: This question is unclear about what kind of monitor will be used and what connections it supports.

Comment: @tofro Questions can be re-opened, so if the OP's real question is not answered by the pointer to the other question, he can [edit] this one to explain what's different from that. However, I it's fair to assume a non-RF connection if the poster hasn't stated otherwise, and the first answer to the other question well covers all the other common and easy options using the A/V port.

Comment: The cables listed in the dupe will work with any TV with a composite input, which goes back quite a while... If necessary, a VCR can serve as intermediary (sticking to contemporary equipment).